# file stream function object c that has a pointer option

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstream

Hey guys I am wondering what options apple have given us with regards to file streams that have an index parameter, so that when the types in a number that represents a line position in the file the function will open the stream go to that index and return the text from that index line.

Comment: Okay, so I have done a whole bunch of searching back over at the developers library and I stumbled across NSFileHandle, which has a method called seekToFileOffSet.. which I think will be just the thing I am looking for. If you have any comments otherwise please let me know as for now I'm gonna give this thing a crack.